# How to find apache PID for child processes on windows?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, process

I have several apache instances and need a way of accurately associating each process with a given configuration for performance monitoring, setting processor affinity, etc.

These actions against the child process will be done with scripts, so I'm looking for a command-line tool or way of configuring apache to dump the child PID to a file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). Microsoft acquired sysinternals that originally created it along with other great products a lot of us System/Network Admins love, pstools.

Comment: I'm looking for a way of getting the PID to be used by management scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [PsList](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682) or another "dos" tools, always from sysinternals.

```
pslist -t apache
```